# ¿como puedo validar un editText sin que se cierre la app cuando le doy al boton?

Tags: java, android-studio, edittext

intento hacer una app que registre datos numericos y luego los sume, para mostrarlos en un segundo activity, pero el problema es que cuando el usuario no ingresa valores en uno de los edittext se cierra la app al momento de dar al boton. la unica manera de que no se cierre es poniendo 0 en los edittext que el usuario quiere dejar en blanco. entonces como puedo hacer para que los no se cierre la app al momento de que el usuario deje un campo de edittext vacio sin la nesecidad de ponerle 0. les dejo el codigo, gracias de antemano!!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText et_2, et_3, et_4, et_5, et_6, et_7, et_8;
private TextView tv_calcular;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    et_3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
    et_4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et4);
    et_5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et5);
    et_6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et6);
    et_7 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et7);
    et_8 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et8);
    tv_calcular = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_calcular);


}

//Metodo para el boton calcular
public void Calcular (View view){

    String valor2 = et_2.getText().toString();
    String valor3 = et_3.getText().toString();
    String valor4 = et_4.getText().toString();
    String valor5 = et_5.getText().toString();
    String valor6 = et_6.getText().toString();
    String valor7 = et_7.getText().toString();
    String valor8 = et_8.getText().toString();

    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(valor2);
    double num3 = Double.parseDouble(valor3);
    double num4 = Double.parseDouble(valor4);
    double num5 = Double.parseDouble(valor5);
    double num6 = Double.parseDouble(valor6);
    double num7 = Double.parseDouble(valor7);
    double num8 = Double.parseDouble(valor8);

    double mult2 = num2*0.40;
    double mult3 = num3*0.30;
    double mult4 = num4*0.35;
    double mult5 = num5*0.50;
    double mult6 = num6*0.25;
    double mult7 = num7*0.65;
    double mult8 = num8*0.55;


    double resultado = mult2 + mult3 + mult4 + mult5 + mult6 + mult7 + mult8;

    String result = String.valueOf(resultado);
    tv_calcular.setText(result);


    Toast.makeText(this, "Calculo con exito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//Metodo para el boton siguiente
public void Siguiente (View view){

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    i.putExtra("dato", tv_calcular.getText().toString());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

Comment: El método `Double.parseDouble` genera una exception cuando el string no contiene la representación de un número. Considera hacer validaciones del contenido como asignarle cero si está vacío y considera también hacer las conversiones dentro de un try-catch

Answer (score 0):

Debes verificar que ninguno de tus EditText te devuelva una cadena vacia

```
public void Calcular (View view){

    String valor2 = et_2.getText().toString();
    String valor3 = et_3.getText().toString();
    String valor4 = et_4.getText().toString();
    String valor5 = et_5.getText().toString();
    String valor6 = et_6.getText().toString();
    String valor7 = et_7.getText().toString();
    String valor8 = et_8.getText().toString();

    if(!valor2.isEmpty()&&!valor3.isEmpty()&&!valor4.isEmpty()&&!valor5.isEmpty()&&!valor6.isEmpty()&&!valor7.isEmpty()&&!valor8.isEmpty()){
        double num2 = Double.parseDouble(valor2);
        double num3 = Double.parseDouble(valor3);
        double num4 = Double.parseDouble(valor4);
        double num5 = Double.parseDouble(valor5);
        double num6 = Double.parseDouble(valor6);
        double num7 = Double.parseDouble(valor7);
        double num8 = Double.parseDouble(valor8);

        double mult2 = num2*0.40;
        double mult3 = num3*0.30;
        double mult4 = num4*0.35;
        double mult5 = num5*0.50;
        double mult6 = num6*0.25;
        double mult7 = num7*0.65;
        double mult8 = num8*0.55;


        double resultado = mult2 + mult3 + mult4 + mult5 + mult6 + mult7 + mult8;

        String result = String.valueOf(resultado);
        tv_calcular.setText(result);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Calculo con exito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    else Toast.makeText(this,"Debes ingresar todos los campos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
}
```

Comment: no me da error, pero no es lo que deseo hacer, ya que si en la app dejo un EditText sin completar me salta el Toast del else... lo que en realidad deseo es que a pesar de que el usuario deje campos de EditText vacios, siempre se realice la suma, o en pocas palabras los campos que queden vacios tomen el valor de 0. sabes como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que tome el valor de 0 (cero) cuando el usuario no escriba nada solo debes declarar una variable con el valor cero y validarlo. Ejemplo:

```
double valorCero = 0;
```

Y en tu método validarlo, algo como esto:

```
if(EditText.getText().ToString()=="" || EditText.Equals("")){
 valorCero = tuEditText.ToString();
 //resto de tu código
}
else {
 //lo que sea que deba hacer en caso de que no esté vacío
}
```

Comment: me da error....

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? @JosueErazo

Comment: Recuerda que `EditText` es en realidad el nombre de tu `EditText`

Comment: me dice que debo cambiar a String la variable que tiene el valor de 0

Comment: o sabes alguna otra manera de que pueda hacer las conversiones en mis variables?? te lo agradeceria bro